# Como posso passar um file descriptor para outro processo?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Recentemente eu li um [post de Peter Hutterer](http://who-t.blogspot.com.br/2017/04/inputfd-protocol-for-direct-access-to.html) explicando sobre um novo protocolo chamado inputfd que se destina a repassar um file descriptor diretamente para outros processos sem a interação do compositor.

Eu fiquei curioso, como é possível passar um file descriptor de um processo para outro?

Poderiam mostrar um exemplo mínimo de código que faça isso?

Comment: Em ambiente UNIX (e Linux) o processo de passagem de um descritor de arquivos entre processos quaisquer é bem conhecido e utiliza a função "sendmsg" entre sockets locais (família AF_UNIX ou AF_LOCAL). Esta página do SOen tem vãrios exemplos de como fazer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003921/sending-file-descriptor-by-linux-socket/.

Comment: @nullptr, era exatamente isso que eu estava buscando. Por favor, poste seu comentário em forma de resposta e vou marcar como a correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em ambiente UNIX (e Linux) o processo de passagem de um descritor de arquivos entre processos quaisquer é bem conhecido e utiliza a função "sendmsg" entre sockets locais (família AF_UNIX ou AF_LOCAL). Esta [página](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003921/sending-file-descriptor-by-linux-socket/) do SOen tem vários exemplos de como fazer.

A primeira vez que vi este exemplo foi num dos livros de W. Richard Stevens, que são a referência básica para programação em ambiente UNIX. 
Infelizmente na Amazon só um deles está disponível no Kindle, [aqui](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DB3G8KY). (A 3ª edição é de outro autor porque WRS morreu faz uns 15 anos).